# undefined method 'cache_sweeper'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I'm trying to setup some caching on my site and am having troubles with getting a cache sweeper working. I followed the [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/89) but when I try to load a page with the model, I'm getting an error. Here's what I've done thus far:

1.) Added the app/sweepers directory and put a basic sweeper in it:

```
class TeamMemberSweeper < ActionController::Caching::Sweeper
  observe TeamMember

  def after_create(team_member)
    expire_nav_menus
  end

  def after_destroy(team_member)
    expire_nav_menus
  end

  private

  def expire_nav_menus(athlete_id)
    expire_fragment(...)
  end
end
```

2.) Add the following line to the TeamMember model:

```
cache_sweeper :team_member_sweeper, :only => [:create, :destroy]
```

3.) Added the following line to config/environment.rb and restarted my server:

```
config.load_paths += %W( #{RAILS_ROOT}/app/sweepers )
```

At this point, whenever I access the TeamMember model I get the following error:

```
undefined method `cache_sweeper' for #<Class:0x23128cc>
```

What I missing to get this working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think because the

"cache_sweeper :team_member_sweeper, :only => [:create, :destroy]"

Should go in the controllers you want to expire in and not the model.

I've ran into similar problems because I specifically WANT to expire from the model, but apparently that's not possible or very hard to do in Rails.

Comment: Yup--you add cache sweepers in the controller, not the model.